# Compress command output by piping to bzip2

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to pipe a command output to bzip2 for compression to an output file?

Something along the lines of:

```
cat somefile.txt | bzip2 --output somefile.txt.bz2
```

Comment: I don't recommend using bzip2, it's slower and has worse compression than xz

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this with `bzip2`'s `-c` option:

```
       -c --stdout
              Compress or decompress to standard output.
```

For example:

```
command | bzip2 -c > some.txt.bz2
```

And to decompress:

```
bzip2 -dc < some.txt.bz2 | less
```

Answer (score 6):

The bzip2 utility will compress stdin but won't write it to stdout if stdout is a terminal. You can though use standard output redirection techniques.

```
command | bzip2 >somefile.txt.bz2
```

and to read it the usual tools are available e.g.

```
bzless somefile.txt.bz2
```

Comment: Strangely the documentation is pretty good for bzip2.